# Managing scheduled functions with threading in Python script

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have to set up a Python script which should be always up & running and should be responsible to call several functions at determined schedules.
I was considering the following approach, which leverages the libraries `pycron` and `threading`, assuming that `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are Python functions defined somewhere else.
My aim is to accomplish the following targets:

1. Run different functions at specific times (with cron-like schedule)
2. Make possible for those function to overlap (= run simultaneously) if needed
3. Avoid that the same function is being started again if the previous run is not finished

```py
import pycron
from threading import Thread
from custom_modules import func1, func2, func3

while True:
    if not t1.is_alive() and pycron.is_now('*/15 * * * *'):  # True every 15th minute
        t1 = Thread(target=func1)
        t1.start()
        time.sleep(60)
    if not t2.is_alive() and pycron.is_now('30 22 * * *'):  # True at 22:30 every day
        t2 = Thread(target=func2)
        t2.start()
        time.sleep(60)
    if not t3.is_alive() and pycron.is_now('0 0 * * SUN'):  # True at midnight on every Sunday
        t3 = Thread(target=func3)
        t3.start()
        time.sleep(60)
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
```

I'm not sure this approach is sound, especially for target (3) mentioned above.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

a minimal eventloop would be as follows, you need to define a "Task" that would determine the time condition and how much is the least delay between successive calls, and when it was last called, then loop over a dictionary of them and start a function only if:

1. time condition is satisfied
2. enough time has passed from last call
3. not currently running (may not be needed depending on how you handle reaching the next task trigger before the last one is finished)

then sleep for 1 second, note that the least delay between successive calls should be long enough so your tasks won't start twice by pycron, (ie: if it runs at a specific minute, you need the least delay to be at least a minute), and then you can remove the `sleep(60)` because the delay check will prevent the task from being triggered repeatedly within the same slot, so you can launch multiple tasks concurrently.

```py
import pycron
from threading import Thread
import time
import datetime

def func1():
    ...
def func2():
    ...
def func3():
    ...
def func4():
    print("running ...")

class Task:
    def __init__(self, func, time_condition, minimum_delay, last_run_time=None):
        self.function = func
        self.time_condition = time_condition
        self.minimum_delay = minimum_delay
        self.last_run_time = last_run_time

tasks = {"task1": Task(func1, '*/15 * * * *', datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)),  # True every 15th minute
         "task2": Task(func2, '30 22 * * *', datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)),  # True at 22:30 every day
         "task3": Task(func3, '0 0 * * SUN', datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)),  # True at midnight on every Sunday
         "task4": Task(func4, '* * * * *', datetime.timedelta(seconds=20))  # always runs, every 20 seconds
         }
threads = {}

while True:
    for task_name, task in tasks.items():
        if pycron.is_now(task.time_condition):  # should start
            # enough time has passed
            if task.last_run_time is None or task.minimum_delay < (datetime.datetime.now() - task.last_run_time):
                if task_name not in threads or not threads[task_name].is_alive():  # tasks not already running
                    task.last_run_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                    print(f"starting task {task_name} at {task.last_run_time}")
                    threads[task_name] = Thread(target=task.function)
                    threads[task_name].start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined a class:

```
import pycron
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime

class ScheduledThread:
    def __init__(self, function, schedule):
        self.function = function
        self.schedule = schedule
        self.thread = None
        self.start_ts = None
    def start(self):
        current_ts = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
        if self.thread is None or not self.thread.is_alive():
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.function)
        if not self.thread.is_alive() and pycron.is_now(self.schedule) and current_ts != self.start_ts:
            self.start_ts = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
            self.thread.start()
```

Which then can be used as follows:

```
from custom_modules import func1, func2, func3

thread1 = ScheduledThread(func1, '*/15 * * * *')
thread2 = ScheduledThread(func2, '30 22 * * *')
thread3 = ScheduledThread(func3, '0 0 * * SUN')

while True:
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    time.sleep(1)
```